# Safari on Mac not updating / redrawing after hover effect

Tags: css, macos, safari, hover, redraw

I've got a safari-specific problem with a hover effect:
When the user moves over a circle, another circle should appear over it (offset).

This works, but when the user moves his cursor off the circles, parts of the hover-circle still remain until the browser redraws the site (not sure if "redraw" is the right term) . You can do this with Cmd+A to select all text, for example. The hover--leftovers will disappear then.

I think an example shows it the best:
http://jsfiddle.net/L81h9hjr/3/

```
<div class="wrap">
  <h1><a href="#"><span>Reply<span>Our services</span></span></a></h1>
</div>
```

The example works flawlessly in other browser I tested, so you need a Mac Safari (I tried 8.0.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a repaint/redraw issue with Safari / webkit (not sure why it's only on Safari and not Chrome).

I worked around this issue by attaching a jQuery event to the hover element that forced it's surrounding/parent elements to redraw (in my case, a hide() and then a show(0)).

```js
  $('.hover-element').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).parents(".containing-element").hide().show(0);
  });
```

Make sure you use show(0) not just show(), for some reason plain old show() doesn't get fired without an animation argument.

Comment: Hi user828591, does the work-around I posted above fix your issue? If so, could you accept it?

Comment: Just FYI, the link is dead.